# using angular 2 http client in es5

Tags: javascript, angular

We are trying to upgrade our angular 1 app to angular 2 module by module; since our existing project is based on es5 we have decided to use the same with angular 2. We have so far figured out upgradeAdapter and DI to some extent but seem to have hit a snag while using http client. Here's the code:

HTML

All the js files related to ng2 get concatenated in ng2.js

ng2.js

```
app = giddh.webApp;

class diTest {
  constructor (){
  }

  get(){
    return 'injected from diTest';
  }
};

console.log(ng.http)

app.AppComponent =
  ng.core.Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [diTest, ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    templateUrl: '/public/webapp/ng2/audit_logs/audit-logs.html'
  })
  .Class({
    constructor:[diTest,ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS, function(di, http) {
      this.test = di.get();
      this.result = {};
      this.http = http;
      this.mapPeople().subscribe(function(result){
        this.result = result;
      }.bind(this));
    }],
    mapPeople: function(){
      return this.http.get('people.json').map(function (res) {
              return res.json();
      });
    }
});

})()



var upgradeAdapter = new ng.upgrade.UpgradeAdapter();

angular.element(document.body).ready(function() {
  upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['giddhWebApp']);
});

// downgrade ng2 components to ng1 directives
app.directive('myApp',     upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(app.AppComponent));
```

The error I get in the console is:

InstantiationError {_wrapperMessage: "DI Exception", _originalException: TypeError: this.http.get is not a function
    at app.AppComponent.ng.core.Component.Class.mapPeople…, _originalStack: "TypeError: this.http.get is not a function↵    at …0 [as viewFactory] (viewFactory_Hostclass0:73:25)", _context: null, _wrapperStack: "Error: DI Exception↵    at InstantiationError.Wrap…ngular2/bundles/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:16347:37)"…} ""

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `Http` instance of `HTTP_PROVIDERS` at the constructor level since it only corresponds to the type of the object you expect to be injected in the constructor:

```
.Class({
  constructor:[diTest,ng.http.Http, function(di, http) { // <---------
    this.test = di.get();
    this.result = {};
    this.http = http;
    this.mapPeople().subscribe(function(result){
      this.result = result;
    }.bind(this));
  }],
```

`HTTP_PROVIDERS` must be only defined when configuring your providers:

```
ng.core.Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [diTest, ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  templateUrl: '/public/webapp/ng2/audit_logs/audit-logs.html'
})
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/3bNQkXNXZVXoPxPF3tiy?p=preview.